# Pass a UIImage from photopicker to a previous ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two UIViewControllers, the first (A) accepts user input and asks if they would like to add a photo. If they tap the "add photo" button, the are pushed to the second (B) viewcontroller. Both view controllers live inside of a navigation controller, and I only have a segue from A to B. I have read other answers, but they all use prepareToSegue, which requires a segue from B back to A, but this doesn't really work because of the navigation controller.

I'm attaching a screenshot of my two viewcontrollers here. Is there a better way to do this (modally)? I'm writing this in Objective-C.

[image: viewcontroller]

Comment: you need to read about custom delegate

Answer (score 0):

In B.h controller you need to create Protocol /delegate above b.h declaration

```
@protocol MyClassImageReturnDelegate <NSObject>   //define delegate protocol
- (void) myClassDelegateMethodThatReturnsImage: (UIImage *) image;  //define delegate method to be implemented within another class
@end
```

In B.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyClassDelegate> delegate; //define MyClassDelegate
```

In B.m

```
- (void) myMethodToReturnImageAndGoBack {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.delegate myClassDelegateMethod:imageThatNeedToreturn]; //this 
}
```

In A.m you need to set this delegate before pushing

`bClassObject.delegate = self;`

and also implement that method as well

```
- (void) myClassDelegateMethodThatReturnsImage: (UIImage *) image {
NSLog(@"Delegates are great!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use block to pass back whatever you want. Before go to B, set the block. Then when finish your job in B, call the block and send the UIImage as a param.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to achieve this.

> 1. Use delegate on B. Set the delegate of B in A in prepareForSegue.
> 2. Save image to sandbox on B, and B postNotification (NSNotificationCenter) to tell A to pickup the photo from sandbox.
> 3. Use singleton and have the photo in memory (maybe not good if photo is large)
> 4. Use custom block method with completionHandler.

All are relatively easy.